# Windows 7 Task Scheduler is giving me an error saying "The specified account name is not valid"?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I am running Windows 7 on a Dell Precision workstation. I started having this issue right after changing my PC name. I get the error message when in the Task Scheduler Library folder and right-click a task to Disable it.

Also, when I click Create Basic Task I get an error saying "Task Scheduler service is not available or the folder does not exist. Verify that the service is running and that the folder exists."

I have already tried the following solutions.
Things I have tried to resolve the issue so far, but have failed:

I also posted on the Microsoft Community support forum here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-winapps/windows-7-task-scheduler-wont-let-me-modifycreate/03034fae-462e-4dfa-bd7a-e328079e0f06?tm=1537553306933&auth=1.

**EDIT**

I was able to fix my Task Scheduler issues by changing my PC back to it's name before it started giving me issues. This makes me believe a path variable isn't being updated properly when changing my PC name, but I've already checked the registry and can't find any entries with my new or old PC name in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Taskcache`.

I still need to change my PC name and be able to use Task Scheduler which I haven't found a solution to yet, so I haven't truly found a solution yet.

Comment: Consider following steps:

  1. Open the Services console (``services.msc``) and check if the Task Scheduler service is running and configured to start automatically; if the service is not running, run it manually and note any error messages.
  2. If the service fails, check Event Viewer console (``eventvwr.msc``) and look for errors from sources: ``TaskScheduler`` and ``Service Control Manager``. Use ``Filter Current Log...`` option on right panel. Try to repeat running the service manually and then hit ``F5`` in the Event Viewer console to check for most recent errors.

Comment: Change another account to check again. Run command line "sfc /scannow" as administrator to make sure all system files is not corrrupted. Rry michal's measure, and if issue persists, try to use process monitor and reproduce the issue to check detail reason.

Comment: I ran the command "sfc /scannow" and it did find and repair corrupt files. However, after restarting my PC I am still getting the same errors as before.

Comment: I also checked Event Viewer for `TaskScheduler` and `Service Control Manager` items and the only items that showed up were informational. No warning or error messages.

Comment: Related: [Bug: Changing computer name isn't reflected in existing Task Scheduler tasks](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/bug-changing-computer-name-isnt-reflected-in/c41d6623-02ce-4abd-80df-0f4b0a580e60) -- apparently this has been reported as a bug but unfortunately the bug report link is dead now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue was after changing my PC name, tasks I had created in Task Manager still had the User in Security Options set to the old PC name. The way to fix this was for every task:

Task Manager > Right-click Task > Properties > Change User or Group... > Enter the object name to select.

For the box "Enter the object name to select" I had to type my account username, not my new PC name. For example, "Alex".

One final note, the "Author" section for the Task will still show the old PC name, but that caused no issues for me.

[image]

Comment: This can take some time on multiple tasks having the old computername. Do you have a powershell script to do that ?

Comment: Sorry @SebMa I don't.

Comment: My computer name hadn't changed, but for some reason it has the user set to `MyName` instead of `ComputerName\MyName` every time I edit the task. All I had to do was click `Change User or Group...`, type my username into the box and click Check Names then OK, and after that I could save the task, input my password and everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but none of the solutions above worked for me. I ended up discovering that you have to enter the user name as `ComputerName\Username` in the text box (along with the password, of course) even if it is a local account. Once I did this, it worked perfectly.

[image]

Comment: <3 it works!....

Comment: Well done, this resolved me issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem on Windows 7 and here is how I solved it:

1. Close Task Scheduler completely if it is open.
2. Open Windows Explorer and navigate to this folder:
       C:\Windows\System32\Tasks
       Note: you need to be an Administrator to be able to open this folder
3. Search in all files for your old Computer name
       Do a case insensitive search!
       Note: these are actually XML files without the .xml file extension
4. Edit the files which have your old Computer name in them  with a Text editor.
       Just change your old Computer name to the new Computer name in all files.
       Be careful not to change anything else in these files!
5. Finally you must download and use this program to repair the tasks you have edited:
       https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Repair-CorruptedTampered-c8d2e975

After the above you should be good and should not receive that error message any longer when you open Task Scheduler.

Answer (score -3):

One of the main reason behind the [task Scheduler service is not available](http://techstuffsarena.com/2019/07/18/task-scheduler-service-is-not-available/) issue is a virus attack
Make sure we run a full scan of the system to fix the issue.